# Presentations that make the Todd-Coxeter algorithm blow up

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the presentation defined, for an integer $n > 1$, by
$$G_{n} = \langle x, y \mid xy^n = y^{n+1}x, yx^{n+1} = x^{n}y\rangle .$$
The group defined by this presentation is trivial.  Is it true that the minimum number of cosets that must be defined by the Todd-Coxeter process before any coincidences occur, when run on this presentation over the trivial subgroup, is bounded below by some (at least linear, probably worse) function of $n$, and is such a lower bound known?  (In practice, this seems to behave quite badly.)

(A special case of this appears in a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833625/suppose-g-is-a-group-generated-by-elements-x-and-y-where-xy2-y3x-and/833677#833677), which is what prompted this one.)

Comment: I have never heard of a theorem proving such a lower bound. You get much faster completion with Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration if you enumerate cosets of the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ rather than the trivial subgroup. It completes very quickly even with $n=100$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, yes you're right. It does still seem to blow up, though, just much more slowly.  But I was mainly curious whether this was one of those examples that was known, or could be shown, to have necessarily bad behaviour. I have an example in my notes of the form $\langle x,y\mid x^ny^{n+1}, x^{n+1}y^{n+2}\rangle$ where it is supposed to require at least $n$ cosets to be defined before any coincidence can occur in Todd-Coxeter.  I thought this might be another such.  Alas, I did not write down the reference. I thought it might have been your "Handbook", but I could not find it there now.

Comment: @DerekHolt. I guess it was obvious what I meant, but I notice that I failed to note that I was referring to an enumeration of the cosets of the trivial subgroup. I've fixed it.